# Elasticsearch: Boost the field for specific values using Mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, field, solr-boost

I am using elasticsearch Version 5.6. I would like to like to boost the field "type" when it's value is video ( "contentType": "video"). Currently my mappings looks like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text", 
        },
        "contentType": {
          "type": "text",
           "boost": 4
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I specify that only boost by 4 where contentType is equal to "video"? I know it can be done on query side, but I would like to do it in my mappings. Is it possible? Any help is appreciated

Comment: i don't think condition based boost is possible inside the elasticsearch mapping ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In elastic 2.x is possible, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/index-boost.html
It's deprecated since 5.0 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/mapping-boost.html. Take a look to the section why index time boosting is a bad idea

Comment: Thanks. Looks like they don't support index time boosting now